# Export Calendar Date to spreadsheetout - Time Stripped off - Google Script

Tags: date, time, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, strip

I am using Google Script to export some calendar events to a spreadsheet; the relevant portion of my script is below:

```
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('')]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,7);
range.setValues(details);
```

This code works but the "time" that is put into the spreadsheet is a real number of the form nnnnn.nn.  On the spreadsheet itself the date looks great using the integer to the left of the decimal (eg 10/15/2017) but the decimals are part of the value and therefore are part of the spreadsheet value.

My script drops the data into a sheet in my workbook, and another sheet reads the rows of data with the above date types, looking for specific date info from the other sheet using the match function (for today()).  That would work fine if I could get rid of the decimals.

How can I use what I have above (if I stray far from what I have found works I will be redoing hours of work) but adding just what is needed to only put into the output spreadsheet the whole number portion so I have a pure date that will be found nicely by my match function using today()?

I have been digging, but errors abound in trying to put it all together.  "Parse" looked like a good hope, but it failed as the validation did not like parse used within getStartTime. Maybe I used it in the wrong manner.

Help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CalendarApp documentation, `getStartTime()` generates a `Date` object. You should be able to extract the date and time separately from the date object:

```
var eventStart = events[i].getStartTime();  // Returns date object
var startDate = eventStart.toDateString();  // Returns date portion as a string
var startTime = eventStart.toTimeString();  // Returns time portion as a string
```

You could then write one or both of these to your spreadsheet. See the w3schools Javascript Date Reference for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

If you If you want to specify the string format, you can try `formatDate` in the `Utilities` service:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format

Comment: Tiffany, thanks! I did more digging and finally figured out what you were tryint to tell me.  I have this working now using:  var eventStart = events[i].getStartTime();  // Returns date object
var startDate = eventStart.toDateString();  // Returns date portion as a string

var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), startDate, myformula_placeholder, ('')]];                 I still to now know why I got the weird integer values using Math.floor, but I have what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeffs, I'm glad it worked out. Please accept my answer since that's what you ended up using!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the Math.floor() function

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp

which will round the real number to an integer. Your line would then read:

```
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), Math.floor(events[i].getStartTime()), myformula_placeholder, ('')]];
```

Comment: Alfie, thank you so much for your input.  I had super high hopes, as it was so crystal clear what I needed to do and how to integrate the math floor into my code.  That was much easier than how Tiffany responded, which I cannot get into my code cleanly to run without errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't  get the result I expected.  Pulling today, August 12, I had pulled 42584.49 which does reflect August 12, midday.  Using the math floor I get an integer of 1471010400000 which I saw unformatted, and presumed this must be milliseconds.  When I divided by 1000x60x60x24 I did not get the 42584 I expected, but rather a date in 1946.  Any idea on what is happening, and how get what I need into my output spreadsheet?